# Storing an UIImage in a custom object fails

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a custom object called `report` with the attributes `comment` and `image`. In a `prepareForSegue`-Method i can easily call `report.comment = "Comment"` This works fine...no problem. Then i want to set the image
and when the new ViewController shows up no image is shown, but the comment was set.

```
if let imageData = valueDict.valueForKey("image")
{
  print(imageData)
  print("Before processing: \(report.image)") //report.image has a standard value; UIImage()
  report.image = UIImage(data: imageData as! NSMutableData, scale: 1.0)!
  print("After processing: \(report.image)")
}
```

I'm sure the first `print()`-statement shows me the original image-data. I get something like `<ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048... and so on`. I also get no error-Message but the image is not shown. it seems like the converting method is not working. After converting i get something like this `<UIImage: 0x7ff6f858bda0>, {1080, 1080}`. Even when i set a static image like `report.image = UIImage(named: "defaultPhoto.png")!` the image is not shown.

I also tried the following calls

```
report.image = UIImage(data: valueDict.valueForKey("image") as! NSData)!
report.image = (valueDict.objectForKey("image") as? UIImage)!
report.image = UIImage(data: valueDict.objectForKey("image"))
report.image = valueDict["image"] as! UIImage
```

But nothing is working. 
So the main Question is: Why is the converting-Method not working as expected.
I know its hard to say wants wrong for someone who does not know the project but maybe you have a hint or an advice what i can check or look for.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

My Prepare for Segue-Method looks like this.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {

        let dtvc: DetailReportTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailReportTableViewController

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! MyReportsTableViewCell
        print("The ReportNumber is: \(cell.reportNumber)")

        for singleReport in listOfAllReports
        {
            if singleReport.key as! String == cell.reportNumber
            {
                print("Bericht gefunden.")
                let valueDict = singleReport.value as! NSDictionary

                report.category = valueDict.objectForKey("category") as! String
                report.comment = valueDict.objectForKey("comment") as! String


                if let dateTime = valueDict.objectForKey("date")
                {
                    let df = NSDateFormatter()
                    df.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyy HH:mm:ss"

                    report.timestamp = df.dateFromString(dateTime as! String)!
                }

                if let locationData = valueDict.valueForKey("location")
                {
                    report.locationData.längengrad = locationData.objectAtIndex(0) as! Double
                    report.locationData.breitengrad = locationData.objectAtIndex(1) as! Double
                }

                if let imageData = valueDict.valueForKey("image")
                {
                    print(imageData)
                    print("Before processing: \(report.image)") //report.image has a standard value; UIImage()
                    report.image = UIImage(data: imageData as! NSMutableData, scale: 1.0)!
                    print("After processing: \(report.image)")
                }

            }

        }
        print("Category: \(report.category)")
        print("Datum: \(report.timestamp)")
        print("Location: \(report.locationData)")
        print("Comment: \(report.comment)")
        print("Image: \(report.image)")

        dtvc.report = report

    }
```

Comment: What does your prepareForSegue look like?

Comment: i edited my post to show you my prepareForSegue-Method

Comment: What does the code look like that displays report.image?

Answer (score 0):

If

> Even when i set a static image...the image is not shown

is true, the problem is likely with the UIImageView, not the image itself.

I'm pretty sure

> UIImage: 0x7ff6f858bda0, {1080, 1080}

is showing the memory location, and the size of the image. (I'm guessing your image is 1080x1080?) so I think you're creating the image correctly, it's just not being displayed.

Check that your image view is visible, not below other views, and properly connected to your nib.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its weird. The value `UIImage: 0x7ff6f858bda0, {1080, 1080}` can't be right. Because i know the original data. So `report.image` has a complete different value than `imageData` although i call `report.image = imageData'. But i will check the imageView again.

Comment: wow, I did it know. i checked my code as you suggested. but it was not the image view. there was one line missing in the destination view controller. I commented out many parts before i guess and somehow i removed the imported line. So there was an allocation missing. Thank you very much to everyone